# jQueryCheckboxes being locked to checked state

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have two forms in different tabs, each crossover field has it's value duplicating to the other form onchange/keyup.

When my checkboxes change there is also a background image change to highlight the selection, for some reason I cannot figure out why but when the checkboxes are turned on they will not turn off again.

jsfiddle link > http://jsfiddle.net/UMwkV/

html

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-form left">                             
        <label>Flammable</label>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="flammable"></div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="flammable" class="flamcheck" name="flammable" value="1" style="width:12px; height:12px; margin:0 auto; display:block; margin-top:5;">
        </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="fieldset-form left">                             
        <label>Flammable</label>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="flammable"></div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="flammable" class="flamcheck" name="flammable" value="1" style="width:12px; height:12px; margin:0 auto; display:block; margin-top:5;">
        </fieldset>
```

jQuery

```
$("input[name=flammable]").change(function() {
    if ($('.flamcheck').is(":checked")) {
        $('.flammable').css("backgroundColor", "url(images/flame-on.png)");
        $('.flamcheck').prop("checked", true);
    }
    if (!$('.flamcheck').is(":checked")) {
        $('.flammable').css("backgroundImage", "url(images/flammable.png)");
        $('.flamcheck').prop("checked", false);
    }

})​
```

If anyone could point out the obvious thing I'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

instead

http://jsfiddle.net/UMwkV/6/

$.is() returns true when at least one element matches the selector. Once when both boxes are checked, when you click on one box again, the other checkbox still will be checked, so is() will always return true when you run it on both checkboxes.

Comment: that explains a few problems I've been experiencing lately! thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>AFAIK `.is(':checked')` runs against the DOM as it was rendered over the wire, not the current live DOM.</strike>

So the solution is to use `.prop('checked')` instead

http://jsfiddle.net/UMwkV/1/

Version 2 allows for independant checking:

http://jsfiddle.net/UMwkV/2/

Version 3 causes mutual updating, and both checkboxes are clickable:

http://jsfiddle.net/UMwkV/8/

Comment: HMM, just realized that checks both checkboxes in unison, code may have to be rewritten to fix that.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be quite working, using the top link, the bottom checkbox fails to be clickable

Comment: @user1372212 what about Version 2?

Comment: V2 doesn't mirror the checked states

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.This code will just work fine

```
$(".flamcheck").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true ) {
   $('.flammable').css("backgroundColor", "url(images/flame-on.png)");
   $('.flamcheck').prop("checked", true);
  }
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
   $('.flammable').css("backgroundImage", "url(images/flammable.png)");
   $('.flamcheck').prop("checked", false);
  }

});
```

Check this- http://jsfiddle.net/UMwkV/10/

Answer (score 0):

check this working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UMwkV/11/)

your code has a syntax error i have corrected it please check the fiddle